# Zoom in/out of draggable image in center of the container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Working on a script to make a photo viewer where user can drag the image and can zoom it keeping the center fix. I am using an jquery slider for zooming image in and out. Basically it should zoom the image in the center of the container. But it keep on jumping while I try to zoom it after some drag. Here you can view some of my code-

```
function resize_img(val)
{
    var maxZoom =50; //50% zoom

    var width=globalElement_width; //original image width
    var height=globalElement_height; //original image height
    var zoom = maxZoom / 100;
    var zoom_percen_w = width * zoom;
    var zoom_percen_h = height * zoom;
    var ASPECT_W = zoom_percen_w / maxZoom;
    var ASPECT_H = zoom_percen_h / maxZoom;
    var zoom_value = val * zoom;
    var setWidth = width + ASPECT_W * zoom_value;
    var setHeight = height + ASPECT_H * zoom_value;

    $img = $('.canvas img');

    var setLeft = 0 -(ASPECT_W * zoom_value/2);
    var setTop = 0 - (ASPECT_H * zoom_value/2);

    $img.css('width',setWidth+'px');
    $img.css('height',setHeight+'px');
    $img.css('left',setLeft+'px');
    $img.css('top',setTop+'px');
    ....................
```

The full demo link- http://jsfiddle.net/hirenbg89/Qv35B/13/

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the current left/top position and change the positioning based on that. From what I can tell you're always starting at 0:

```
var setLeft = 0 -(ASPECT_W * zoom_value/2);
var setTop = 0 - (ASPECT_H * zoom_value/2);
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But I am not abling to find an way to do it. What I was trying is to do this-
 
    `var setLeft =image.position().left - (ASPECT_W * zoom_value/2);`
    `var setTop =image.position().top - (ASPECT_H * zoom_value/2);`

I know it is not correct. can you suggest me the right way to do so.